# Waring's Inequality Solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-verification, open-problem

$$
\text{Waring's problem asks, "Is }\left\lfloor \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{3^n-1}{2^n-1}\right\rfloor\text{ always true?"}
$$

We craft an inequality, with $m,n \in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$,

$$
\frac{(2 m-1) 3^n-1}{(2 m-1) 2^n-1}<\left\lceil \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n\right\rceil,
$$
where $(2m-1)$ is the $m$-th odd number. Note: when $m=1$, this is the floor item as shown at top right.

Some representative results: **Edit to set domain to integers**
$$
 m\in \mathbb{Z}\land n=1\land m\geq 2 \\
 m\in \mathbb{Z}\land n=2\land m\geq 1 \\
 m\in \mathbb{Z}\land n=3\land m\geq 1 \\
 m\in \mathbb{Z}\land n=400\land m\geq 1 \\
$$
Take $n\rightarrow\infty$ and we have Waring's Problem solved.

Q: Do we need more?

Q2: Can you spot the error in my answer?

Comment: What steps?​​​​​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, it is trivial that for any natural number $n \ge 1$
$$ \lfloor (3/2)^n \rfloor \lt (3/2)^n \lt \lceil  (3/2)^n \rceil $$
and it is also easy to find that
$$  (3/2)^n \lt {m \cdot 3^n-1\over m \cdot 2^n-1}  \qquad \text{for $m \ge 1$ }$$
What you are looking for is a ***proof***, that
$$  {m \cdot 3^n-1\over m \cdot 2^n-1} \lt \lceil  (3/2)^n \rceil \qquad \text{for all $m \ge 1$ } $$
or, in the form of (exclusion of) a single counterexample, 
$$  {m \cdot 3^n-1\over m \cdot 2^n-1} \gt \lceil  (3/2)^n \rceil \qquad \text{for at least one $m \ge 1$ } $$
What you show is ***evidence***, giving good reason to assume your hypothese (which is always worth some effort!). Now your list stops at example 400 - but that's not enough to show this holds up to 4000 , 40000, 400000, ... and so on, without any bound.
What you still need is a proof, for instance

- by ***mathematical induction***, which would enable you to conclude from the correctness for a given pair $(n,m_n)$ to the correctness for a next pair $(n+1,m_{n+1})$ (where the complete proof can then also be rooted at some $n \ge1 $)
- by some ***modular argument*** (perhaps like Kurt Mahler with his treatize on Z-numbers (see for instance Mathworld, I hope I've put this here correctly)
- or possibly by some argument of approximation of transcendental numbers (like ratio  $\ln(3) \ln(2) $ ) to rational numbers (as Ray Steiner proceeded in his 1996-proof and John Simons and Benne de Weger later (see references in wikipedia))
- maybe some other argument.

A ***list for increasing the evidence*** shall never be enough! For an entertaining break look at MSE or MO for examples of "law of small numbers" *( I think that's the correct term, perhaps I can give more concrete references later, but I'm out on holiday and don't knwo when I can come back to this)* There are a couple of "big lists" there as I know.

Comment: I figured the closed form sequence would be enough for _induction_.